# What am I missing here? (ProjectEuler P017)

Tags: python, string

So, I'm having trouble reviewing this simple code:

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
b = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']
c = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']
d = ['hundred', 'thousand', 'and']
e = a + b + c + d

sum_0 = 0
for i in e:
    sum_0 += len(i)

# 21, 22.. 99
sum_1 = 0
for i in c:
    for j in a:
        sum_1 += len(i + j)

# 100, 200.. 900
sum_2 = 0
for i in a:
    sum_2 += len(i + d[0])

# 101, 102.. 909
sum_3 = 0
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        sum_3 += len(i + d[0] + d[2] + j)

# 110, 111.. 119
sum_4 = 0
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        sum_4 += len(i + d[0] + d[2] + j)

# 120, 130.. 990
sum_5 = 0
for i in a:
    for j in c:
        sum_5 += len(i + d[0] + d[2] + j)

# 121, 122.. 999
sum_6 = 0
for i in a:
    for j in c:
        for k in a:
            sum_6 += len(i + d[0] + d[2] + j + k)
```

When I `print sum_0 + sum_1 + sum_2 + sum_3 + sum_4 + sum_5 + sum_6 + 3`, I get 21134, which is 10 more than the right answer. What am I missing here?

*By the way, the `3` after `sum_6` is the length of 'one' in 'one thousand'

Comment: Refers to http://projecteuler.net/problem=17

Comment: Just a comment: solving projecteuler problems is not brute-forcing to the solution with a horribly messy code, but thinking about the problem by yourself and trying to find a nice and elegant algorithm which does the calculation within few seconds.

Comment: @septi I'm relatively new to programming and python.

Comment: @Deneb This question would be better posted to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting `100 (one hundred)` twice.

First time here (actually `'hundred', 'and'` are used, but `one` and `and` are both three letters long):

```
d = ['hundred', 'thousand', 'and']
e = a + b + c + d

sum_0 = 0
for i in e:
    sum_0 += len(i)
```

Second time here:

```
# 100, 200.. 900
sum_2 = 0
for i in a:
    sum_2 += len(i + d[0])
```